# What could cause the JVM to crash with SIGSEGV "ClassLoaderData::metaspace_non_null()"

Tags: java, memory, jvm, spring-cloud, segmentation-fault

We are running around 40 JVM processes on one of our machines (3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.78-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux). The server has 32GB memory and each of the processes is consuming something between 350 to 380MB memory. Each process hosts a Spring Boot application. From time to time, we see one of the JVMs crashing with the error below.

```
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f151891d5d0, pid=3049, tid=0x00007f14fa784700
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

V  [libjvm.so+0x4685d0]  ClassLoaderData::metaspace_non_null()+0xc0
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a17e0]  Metaspace::allocate(ClassLoaderData*, unsigned long, bool, MetaspaceObj::Type, Thread*)+0x170
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b4b46]  MethodCounters::allocate(ClassLoaderData*, Thread*)+0x26
V  [libjvm.so+0x8ac8b1]  Method::build_method_counters(Method*, Thread*)+0x71
V  [libjvm.so+0x681adb]  InterpreterRuntime::build_method_counters(JavaThread*, Method*)+0x2b
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor18988.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
J 10626 C2 org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Object; (405 bytes) @ 0x00007f1509f7cca8 [0x00007f1509f77ec0+0x4de8]
J 11391 C2 org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.DataCenterAwareMarshallingStrategy$PublishingApplicationsConverter.unmarshal(Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamReader;Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/UnmarshallingContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (39 bytes) @ 0x00007f1509a8fee4 [0x00007f1509a8f4c0+0xa24]
J 11352 C2 org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.DataCenterAwareMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamReader;Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/DataHolder;Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterLookup;Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/mapper/Mapper;)Ljava/lang/Object; (30 bytes) @ 0x00007f1509a344cc [0x00007f1509a33da0+0x72c]
J 12523 C2 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object; (246 bytes) @ 0x00007f150a3cbf94 [0x00007f150a3cb0e0+0xeb4]
J 11327 C2 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(Z)Z (409 bytes) @ 0x00007f1509b4e7f0 [0x00007f1509b4e400+0x3f0]
J 11332 C2 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run()V (353 bytes) @ 0x00007f1509b49004 [0x00007f1509b48f60+0xa4]
...
```

This happened with processes for different services and on different machines without any apparent reason. But it is always the same stacktrace that we see where the Eureka client is trying to unmarshal a response from the server. But we don't if it only ever fails here because

1. of some weird constellation in the code (Spring, cglib, xstream, Eureka, ...)
2. it is just likely to happen here, because the discovery client polls the server every 30s at all times and is just a likely candidate to run into a weird constellation in the system (memory allocation, fragmentation, ...)

Although we are using Oracle JDK, out of desperation I have checked [the OpenJDK implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/59a58e20dc60/src/share/vm/classfile/classLoaderData.cpp#l320) of this method, but did not get any immediate idea of what could be wrong.

I filed a bug report at Oracle and exchanged a few email with them, but besides saying that without a reproducer for this issue they could not do anything, I got no response from them.

So my question is this - what possible reasons are there to cause such an error in the JVM? We suspected too high memory fragmentation when we previously saw this error on a system with less memory that was around 2% free memory, but I find it unlikely that this is the case on the new system where memory consumption is only around 70%. What other other explanations for this failure are there, other than a bug in the JVM implementation? And most importantly - what could we try to reliable reproduce this error?

Comment: The error seems to come from the native libs during reflections (libjvm.so). Most issues I found on the net seems to be related to JDK bugs. it make senses since SIGSEGV should be caused by bad memory allocation manipulation. We usually don't go that low with Java. I would recommend you to update your oracle JDK or even deploy some of your instances with an OpenJDK for testing purposes. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

It will be nice, if you provide full crash report. 
From this small stack trace I see one interesting part

> sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor18988

this means that you have 18988 generated accessors in your application ( I think it's much ). You can see here `sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator`.
When you use serialization or reflection, this can generate new classes ( `sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator#generate` ) and then each class will be defined in DelegatingClassLoder, which will be created each time ( `sun.reflect.ClassDefiner#defineClass`).

Try to increase inflation threshold

> -Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold = some big big number

It will defer generating of new accessors.

---

Also you can view via JMX how many classes are unloaded ( ClassLoading MBean ),
and also you can run

> jcmd %pid% PerfCounter.print

and monitor counters
`sun.gc.metaspace.capacity`
`sun.gc.metaspace.maxCapacity`
`sun.gc.metaspace.used`